# custom scrollbar in UIWebView iphone

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, iphone

My UIWebView has a huge data to display and the default scrollbar that comes with UIWebview takes lot of time to scroll.

Is it possible to implement a scrollbar on which user can tap and drag that were he wants.

Any hint in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Waiting for your reply.
Thanks in advance

Comment: anyone can give some hint on this plz

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of the contents you are displaying in UIWebview.

Did you try make use of Javascript calls to scroll to certain ids within your html page?

Take a look at the wikipedia application or Wikipanion for iPhone for example... They have navigation screen so the user can jump to the section of their interest without the need to scroll the whole page.

hope that will help.

Comment: I have plain huge text files. they are not HTML files. I am using WEBView to display it as it has a default scroller. and I want to implement a custom scroller. Like many ebook app in iphone have or even dropbox has the scroller to view the content.